# Shell commands from the top-level

Tags: swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

Apparently, I can use some shell commands from the top-level,

```
?- pwd.
/home/boris
true.
```

Others that work are `ls`, `cd`. Any idea where those are documented, or what others there are?

(This is on Linux, can't check if it also work on Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is library(shell), apparently autoloaded, not included in the official manual.

A link to the source: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/shell.pl?show=src